# Searching the output of a program through Terminal

Tags: terminal

Suppose my C++ program has outputted a lot of stuff to the terminal, say a 10000x3 matrix. 
Is there any Unix command-line utility for me to inspect the lines which contain a desired number/string?

In other words if the output looks like

1.23 4.56 7.89

1.54 ***9.86*** 7.78

6.78 1.23 ***9.86***

4.56 6.77 8.98

***9.86*** 3.45  7.54

Some unix command should search this output for 9.86 and print only the lines containing this number .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `mycppprogram | grep '9.86'`

Comment: Thank you, but in my case I want to search the terminal output for a string not a file like mycppprogram.

Comment: The first argument to grep is the pattern (string) to search for. When no files are specified to search, it searches standard input. Use a pipe to channel the output of your program to the standard input of grep. In my example "mycppprogram" is the program that you were running from the command line, the program whose output you want to search.

Comment: Thank you imm! That worked nicely for me. I like the way how grep highlights the searched string in red. One tiny correction in your answer: in my machine `./mycppprogram | grep '9.86'` works. Without the `./` I get `mycppprogram command not found`.

Answer (score 2):

grep is your friend : `man grep`